# Appending into file

Tags: perl

So I'm a brand new to writing scripts and I am currently using Perl. I wrote a script and the very last thing I need it to do is append the output in a .txt file that is already there. I've been trying to get a simple script to work that appends to see if my syntax is correct and it is not working. Advice?

```
#Appending.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $appending_test;


open(my $APPENDING, ">>$appending_test");
print $APPENDING "I am appending";
```

Comment: `$appending_test` is empty.

Comment: I wrote PLACEHOLDER within the text file so I know that its there if thats what you mean

Comment: Hint: don't hardcode any filenames of input or output files into scripts. Specify them in the call instead.  `Appending.pl >> whatever.txt`

Comment: Hint2: make the `>>` a separate argument. See [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Comment: Hint 3: [you may need to `flush` or `close` the filehandle before all output is written to it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush/unbuffer-an-output-filehandle%3F-Why-must-I-do-this%3F). (Output can be buffered.)

Comment: @reinierpost Not working. I thought it might of been the `close` command that I needed but even then still

Comment: Try `print $!;` after the `open` command - you might get a useful error message.

Comment: No error message at all...@DavidKnipe

Comment: @reinierpost: Your comnment about using `'>>'` as a separate parameter is good advice, but not the cause of the problem. Your other comments are misleading, particularly the one that says the OP's code ought to work. As others have pointed out, the variable `$appending_test` has the value `undef` so the open will fail.

Comment: @Borodin: I thought that went without repeating.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify a filename for open() to open...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $filename = 'output.txt';

open my $fh, '>>', $filename
  or die "Can't open the file $filename: $!";

print $fh "I am appending...\n";
```

As just a side note, the more idiomatic way to open a file is to use the three-arg open, and output a statement with the error message if the open fails as I have done in the code snip above.

Comment: While I agree it's bad practice to use `">>$appending_test"` instead of `">>", $appending_test`, you should make it clear that this is just a side remark and not actually an answer to the question. Otherwise it's probably just confusing.